# Renaming dataframe column name

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df_one, df_two like below:

```
df_one.show()

-------------
|Column_Name|
-------------
|NAME       |
|ID         | 
|COUNTRY    |
-------------

df_two.show()

-------------   
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
-------------
|AAA|001|US |
|BBB|002|UK |
|CCC|003|IN |
|DDD|004|FR |
-------------
```

I am trying to rename the column of dataframe df_two like below:

```
------------- ----  
|NAME|ID |COUNTRY|
------------------
|AAA |001| US    |
|BBB |002| UK    |
|CCC |003| IN    |
|DDD |004| FR    |
------------------
```

for time being i created seq and getting the above result

```
val newColumn = Seq("NAME", "ID", "COUNTRY")
val df = df_two.toDF(newColumn:_*)
```

But now I have to read column(Column_Name) from df_one and rename the column name of dataframe df_two respectively.

I also tried to read the column  value from df_one but its returning Seq[Any] and i need Seq[String] .

guide me with some code here ..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in Scala.

Since `df_one` is a small dataset (even if total number of columns is in thousands), one can `collect` the DataFrame as an `Array`.  Now, `collect`-ing the DataFrame would result in an `Array` of `Row`s:

```
df_one.collect
// res1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([NAME], [ID], [COUNTRY])
```

To unwrap the `Row`s (of a single `String`), simply apply `Row` method [`getString`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@getString(i:Int):String):

```
df_one.collect.map(_.getString(0))
// res2: Array[String] = Array(NAME, ID, COUNTRY)
```

Putting it altogether:

```
val df_one = Seq(
  "NAME", "ID", "COUNTRY"
).toDF("Column_Name")

val df_two = Seq(
  ("AAA", "001", "US"),
  ("BBB", "002", "UK"),
  ("CCC", "003", "IN"),
  ("DDD", "004", "FR")
).toDF("_c0", "_c1", "_c2")

val colNames = df_one.collect.map(_.getString(0))

df_two.toDF(colNames: _*).show
// +----+---+-------+
// |NAME| ID|COUNTRY|
// +----+---+-------+
// | AAA|001|     US|
// | BBB|002|     UK|
// | CCC|003|     IN|
// | DDD|004|     FR|
// +----+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_two.columns = df_one['Column_Name']
```